# Open website and save as image

Tags: python, web

I am currently using the following code to open a website:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://test.com')
```

I am now trying to save the open webpage as a .gif, any advise on how to do this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `selenium` and its [`save_screenshot()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.save_screenshot)?

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://test.com")

driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")

driver.close()
```